# AutomationDesk huge reports

Tags: html, automation, dspace

I am currently using AutomationDesk version 5.4 for launching numerous tests coupled with a dSpace Simulator.

The problem I am experiencing relates to the generation of the html report. When this becomes relatively large (greater than 100mb), it is impossible to open it.

I would therefore like to know if there is a way to insert something like 'split reports' within the test sequence and thus obtain several split reports instead of one huge one.

Given the huge amount of tests present, it would be complicated and particularly messy to split the test sequence into dozens of sub-sequences. This is something I have already tried to do, splitting the main sequence into 10 sequences, but the reports turn out to be too big to be opened, so it is not a feasible route to take.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the reports library you will find the CreateSubreport. Place it at a certain hierarchy level and everything at this level or below will be placed in a subreport. In the main report you will find only a link.